# App crashed when using custom presentation transition

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently working on a project using **custom transition between view controllers**. In my storyboard, I control drag a button to another view controller to do a present modally transition, and in the presenting view controller's file I override the `prepareForSegue` method, the code is:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.destinationViewController is RightEyeViewController {
        let rightEyeVC = segue.destinationViewController as RightEyeViewController
        rightEyeVC.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
        rightEyeVC.transitioningDelegate = RightEyeTransitioningDelegate()
    }
}
```

And in the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` I return the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` that I created, the code is:

```
func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    let animationController = RightEyeAnimatedTransitioning()
    animationController.isPresentation = true
    return animationController
}
```

The problem is every time the **app crashes** at the line `return animationController`, but after I add a break point before this line, the transition works without any problems, I don't know what caused this problem, can anyone offer some help!

Comment: Should you be returning an optional here? seems like the code is pretty straightforward. Unless RightEyeAnimatedTransitioning() has a failable initializer?

Comment: I tried to using an optional, but that didn't help either and I don't think the RightEyeAnimatedTransitioning has a failable initializer because the object has properly initialized when the app crashed.

Comment: The function signature states that you are returning an optional. You are not returning an optional. Removing the `?` at the end of your function signature may help, or at least make your code a little better

Comment: OMG!! That does help! But why when I try to make the animationController as the type `RightEyeAnimatedTransitioning?` doesn't help?